# What were the reasons for the OKH purge of pro-Nazi officers in 1938?

Tags: nazi-germany

While reading a biography of Walter Model on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Model), I found this fragment:

> [...]Model was a supporter of the Nazi Party, and his time in Berlin brought him into contact with senior members of the government, but after General der Artillerie Franz Halder became chief of staff of the OKH in September 1938, **there was a purge of pro-Nazi officers from OKH**, and Model was reassigned, becoming the chief of staff of the IV Corps in Dresden.

[OKH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberkommando_des_Heeres) stands for "Oberkommando des Heeres", the high command of German Army. This would suggest that [Franz Halder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Halder) was the reason for that purge, but it seems that Halder was also a pro-Nazi

> During the 1937 Wehrmacht manoeuvres, **Halder met Adolf Hitler and became a loyal supporter**. This personal contact also enabled him to progress through the ranks quickly.[...]Halder was approached by conservative nationalist officers about heading the envisaged coup d'état should Hitler start a war, but he declined.

So in 1938 we have a pro-Nazi chief of OKH and scandals that outer generals Blomberg (married a former prostitute) and Fritsch (falsely accused of homosexuality) even more strengthened Nazi power within Wehrmacht.

So who and why would start removing Nazi supporters from the army headquarters when the Party is at the height of its power? The quote above mentions about anti-Nazis, but how could they be powerful enough to remove someone like Model? The [Oster conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oster_conspiracy) and [Wilhelm Canaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Canaris#Munich_Agreement_and_intrigue), head of Abwehr, as an opponent of the war and Hitler come to my mind, but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: @njuffa the Bloomberg-Fritsch was just another way to grab for power. I watched a few TV shows going a bit deeper about it, but the Wiki article sums it up: Bloomberg fell in love with an "unacceptable" woman and Fritsch was framed (there was a case against a **captain** not **general** Fritsch but Himmler conveniently changed the accused's rank).

Comment: Did you do any research on this purge (who else was affected, etc)? Sharing what you've found would be extremely helpful so that we do not have to retrace your steps.

Comment: Could this be an allusion to the [Oster conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oster_conspiracy)?